# How do I boot a virtual machine from my downloaded .iso file?

Tags: virtualbox

I Have the latest version of VirtualBox (Oracle), but I have no clue how to create a virtual machine. I went to the site  http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and Downloaded 32bit Ubuntu.

The problem is that I can't get the Virtual machine to boot, when it starts it displays the Message "FATAL: NO BOOTABLE MEDIUM FOUND"

How do I correctly set up an Ubuntu VM with VirtualBox?

Answer (score 1):

Before starting the virtual machine:

1. In the VirtualBox main window click on your virtual machine in the left column.  Then click Settings at the top of the window.
2. Click Storage in the left hand column.
3. On the Storage page, click on the CD icon in the center column (it should say Empty beside it).  An new icon of a CD will appear at the right of the window.
4. Click on the icon of the CD over on the right side (the one with an arrow pointing down).
5. Click on "Choose a virtual CD/DVD blah blah blah" in the menu that drops down.
6. Navigate to where you downloaded the installer.iso file.  Click on this file and click Open at the bottom of this window.  The file name you chose should then appear beside the icon of the CD in the center column.
7. Click OK at the bottom of the storage page and start the virtual machine.  It should boot off the .iso just as if it were a physical one.

Comment: I edited it to show you how enumerated lists in Markdown work. If it does not please you, you may feel free to use the rollback feature and revert it to your original state. I'll delete my two comments above.

Comment: Thanks, I will play around and see what I was doing wrong.